# Microsoft Access Time Formatting

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a large data set with a time field containing time records in a short text format (i.e.- 0100, 1230, 1830, 2359). I need to add a colon between each entry so that it can be formatted into a datetime field (i.e.- 01:00:00, 12:30:00, 18:30:00, 23:59:00). How can this process be done within Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add the colon do something like

```
Result = Left(value,2) & ":" & right(value,2)
```

But probably you better use something like:

```
TimeSerial(Left(value,2), right(value,2),0)
```